# View data from the database

Tags: c#, html, css, database, show

this year I need to build a project on HTML
I choose to build a store so I build a database for all the items (i call it items)
every item has a logo(link to photo), name, price, and description.
and now I want to show all the items on the main page (every single item on an item card)
but! I need to show it Dynamically(That it will only show products that exist in the database)
I try to do it with function with response.write but it did not succeed...
If you can help it would be great!

Comment: What database are you using and what are the backend written in? I Assume since question is tagged c#, it's .NET Framework or .NET Core. Will you be using Server-side rendering or Web APIs? Please elaborate.

Comment: Hi imanuel, if you want proper help make sure to post relevant info and a [reprex]. People are alreay trying to guess, that's not how SO works.

Answer (score 1):

Create web APIs of return Json type in MVC architecture with C# and include and display the Jquery library in the project.

Jquery library CDN link in;
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js

Example backend code;

```
public JsonResult AllProduct() 
{
    var list = db.products.ToList(); //products name table
    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

To connect with jquery in html page;

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "AllProduct",
   contentType: "application/json",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(response) {
      $("#table").html(response); //Example #table div show return all value
   },
   error: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The database is unknown so let me try to explain the logic. Let me give an example over MVC since you use c# and html tags by definition. In Razor view it will look like below

```
@foreach(var product in ProductList){
   <div>
       <div><img src="@product.logoImgConvertedToBase64" /></div>
       <div>@product.name</div>
       <div>@product.price</div>
       <div>@product.description</div>
   </div>
}
```

Comment: it not work where to write it?